# Google Earth Callbacks Not Firing

Tags: javascript, dom-events, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to get the Google Earth callbacks to work, but they don't seem to be firing for me.  I've used the [View Change Example](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/event-viewchange.html) at the Google Earth API site as a reference, and see no difference between it and my code... yet mine doesn't work!

Here are the important bits of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ge;

google.load("earth", "1");

function init() {
  document.getElementById('map3d').innerHTML = '';
  google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);
}

function initCallback(pluginInstance) {
  ge = pluginInstance;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

  // add a navigation control
  ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

  // Set the FlyTo speed.
  ge.getOptions().setFlyToSpeed(ge.SPEED_TELEPORT);

  // add some layers
  //ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
  //ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, true);

  throw (new Error("InitCallback!"));

  google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getView(), 'viewchange', function () {
      throw (new Error("EVENT!"));
  });

}

function failureCallback(errorCode) {
}
</script>
```

The "InitCallback!" error is thrown properly, but I never see the "EVENT!" error thrown -- no matter how much I move the globe around.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert on javascript stuff, but if you replace:

```
       throw (new Error("EVENT!"));
```

with an alert instead eg:

```
       alert('EVENT!');
```

I bet you will find it will work. ie the eventListener IS working, it just doesn't seem to like the 'throw' command

Comment: Unfortunately the event truly is not firing.  Doing this replacement does not cause an alert to pop up.  The original code - throw(new Error(...)) - is quick-dirty way to print something to the error console for debug purposes.  But ultimately nothing I put in the event callback is being called.

Comment: Thats funny, because if you go to the view change example page you mentioned, and click on the 'play with this sample at the google code playground' button - On that page, when I put a 'throw' into the initCallback() it will work, but a 'throw' inside the eventListener will NOT work. An alert however will work in both places - although one inside the eventlistener causes my browser to freeze :)

Comment: Weird.  I don't know why it didn't work before... I may have had something else sitting around that was causing issue.  The events are indeed firing and removing the throw(Error()) fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

lifeIsGood is right - when you throwing an error like you have above without a try catch block will cause the js after the thrown error not to execute.

instead use `console.log('Error');` if you are simply trying to use a "quick-dirty way" to print something in the console...

```
function initCallback(pluginInstance) {
     ge = pluginInstance;
     ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

     //throw (new Error("InitCallback!")); -- change this to 
     console.log('InitCallback!');

     google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getView(), 'viewchange', function () {
         //throw (new Error("EVENT!")); -- change this to
         console.log('EVENT!');
     });

}
```